# cargo list showing my command but not a description

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I built and test a cargo command I'm developing.
In the Cargo.toml I've both the `description` and `readme` properties set.

I install:
`cargo install cargo-mycommand --path .`

Builds and installs fine as well as performs as expected.

However; when I do a `cargo-list` I see `mycommand` but no description like the other commands in the list have.

Is there some other flag/setting I'm not finding?

Comment: looks like you fall into this line https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/46c9b51957e335ad03051ae8c513f3ba2a55b3b2/src/bin/cargo/cli.rs#L149 and there is no other parameter. this may be bug, better to open an issue in github.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil - Thanks, I've opened issue there.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10403